# How do get jekyll server running on SELinux

Tags: ruby, linux, github, jekyll

I have to update a github site so i installed SELinux and ran the following commands:

```
sudo yum install  ruby ruby-devel ruby-irb ruby-rdoc rub-ri

sudo yum install rubygems

gem install jekyll
```

After installing everything  I cloned the site from github but once I run

```
jekyll --server
```

I get the following error:

```
[jxsmith@localhost xxx.github.com]$ jekyll --server
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:385:in `require_program': program version required (Commander::Runner::CommandError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:384:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:384:in `require_program'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:52:in `run!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:8:in `run!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/import.rb:10
        from /usr/bin/jekyll:19
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/bin/../lib/jekyll/filters.rb:2
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/bin/../lib/jekyll.rb:44
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/bin/jekyll:7
        from /usr/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/jekyll:19
```

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll requires at least version 1.9.3 of Ruby.

I would suggest you update this, then try following the steps in [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages#installing-jekyll).

Comment: ok, where does it say that jekyll requires version 1.9.3 of ruby?

Comment: The guide I linked to says it, I can't find any version information on the Jekyll site just now. It doesn't work with earlier versions.